# In Recursive dynamic Angular component checkbox selection handling

Tags: angular

Here I'm facing a problem in the parent checkbox select and deselect if I click the parent checkbox all children will be selected if uncheck the child checkbox it's not changing the parent checkbox selection

I want to achieve dynamic change in parent checkbox selection based on children checked or unchecked (i tried so many ways but was unable to get parent info)

here you can check my stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jjebba?file=package.json,src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: just a curious question. Have you tried a reactive form group approach? or do you need it to be just with the data object?

Comment: I didn't try with the form-group approach if we use form group also how we can handle the parent checkbox because the same input we are using for parent and child (just embedding view) @FlorenciaCames

Comment: Can you try this one?  Not complete one, just an idea.. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tlnpfy?file=src/app/components/tree-table/tree-table.component.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the array reference and loop all child elements checked or not. Here is the working version in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ktxpwp?file=src/app/components/tree-table/tree-table.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks for your time, and effort. I appreciate your help this solution is working fine.